# Dynamic Call to processor by request type

Tags: c#, dynamic-programming

Maybe my problem is easy but I became so confuse because I am so new to dynamic programming.

Here is the issue:
I have an Interface which is called IGame. and I have two other interfaces IGameRequest and IGameProcessor.

```
public interface IGame {}
public interface IGameRequest: IGame {}
public interface IGameProcessor: IGame
{ void process();}

public interface IKidGameRequest : IGameRequest {}
public interface IKidGameProcessor : IGameProcessor 
{ void process();}
```

On the other hand,

```
public class KidGameRegistrationRequest : IKidRelatedRequest {//something}
```

So in total I have something like below

```
                         IGame
                   |                    |
              IGameRequest         IGameProcessor
                   |                     |
            IKidGameRequest        **IKidGameProcessor**
                   |                     
           **KidGameRegistrationRequest **
```

I try to find KidGameProcessor when I receive KidGameRegistrationRequest in runtime.

I have tried to fetch all assemblies and search for any with *Kid* name and to prevent any static string, I added an enum class, *GameType*and I managed to find the right processor, but I stuck to invoke that method in runtime.

```
Public enum GameType {Kid}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem. All you describe is what you are doing.

Comment: `: IKidRelatedRequest` Is this a typo?

Comment: @Jimenemex what I like to do is to find proper processor by request type. And the system structure is like what I explained.

Comment: This was just so similar example from actual system